# Error in pytorch data loader batch cycles

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, pytorch-dataloader

I keep getting this error in sagemaker when iterating through pytorch dataloader batch cycles:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 371, in <module>
    g_scaler=g_scaler, d_scaler=d_scaler, runtime_log_folder=runtime_log_folder, runtime_log_file_name=runtime_log_file_name)
  File "main.py", line 78, in train_fn
    for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(loop):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1171, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 525, in __next__
    (data, worker_id) = self._next_data()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1252, in _next_data
    return (self._process_data(data), w_id)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1299, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 429, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/exceptions.py", line 84, in __init__
    super(HTTPClientError, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/exceptions.py", line 40, in __init__
    msg = self.fmt.format(**kwargs)
KeyError: 'error'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-81655136a841> in <module>
     58                             py_version='py3')
     59 
---> 60 pytorch_estimator.fit({'train': Runtime.dataset_path}, job_name=Runtime.job_name)
     61 
     62 #print(pytorch_estimator.latest_job_tensorboard_artifacts_path())

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name, experiment_config)
    955         self.jobs.append(self.latest_training_job)
    956         if wait:
--> 957             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
    958 
    959     def _compilation_job_name(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
   1954         # If logs are requested, call logs_for_jobs.
   1955         if logs != "None":
-> 1956             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   1957         else:
   1958             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type)
   3751 
   3752         if wait:
-> 3753             self._check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
   3754             if dot:
   3755                 print()

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
   3304                 ),
   3305                 allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
-> 3306                 actual_status=status,
   3307             )
   3308 

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job 2022-06-03-05-16-49-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/opt/conda/bin/python3.6 main.py --runtime_var dataset_name=U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18,job_name=2022-06-03-05-16-49-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training,model_name=pix2pix"

  0%|          | 0/248 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  0%|          | 1/248 [00:30<2:07:28, 30.97s/it]
  0%|          | 1/248 [00:30<2:07:28, 30.97s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 371, in <module>
    g_scaler=g_scaler, d_scaler=d_scaler, runtime_log_folder=runtime_log_folder, runtime_log_file_name=runtime_log_file_name)
  File "main.py", line 78, in train_fn
    for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(loop):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1171, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 525, in __next__
    (data, worker_id) = self._next_data()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1252, in _next_data
    return (self
```

Here is the code which results in the error:

```
def train_fn(disc, gen, loader, opt_disc, opt_gen, l1, bce, g_scaler, d_scaler,runtime_log_folder,runtime_log_file_name):

    total_output=''
    
    loop = tqdm(loader, leave=True)
    device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

    print("Loop")
    print(loop)
    print("Length loop")
    print(len(loop))
    for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(loop): #<--error happens here
        print("Loop index")
        print(idx)
        print("Loop item")
        print(x,y)
        x = x.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)
        
        # train discriminator
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            y_fake = gen(x)

            D_real = disc(x, y)
            D_fake = disc(x, y_fake.detach())
            # use detach so as to avoid breaking computational graph when do optimizer.step on discriminator
            # can use detach, or when do loss.backward put loss.backward(retain_graph = True)

            D_real_loss = bce(D_real, torch.ones_like(D_real))
            D_fake_loss = bce(D_fake, torch.ones_like(D_fake))

            D_loss = (D_real_loss + D_fake_loss) / 2
            
            # log tensorboard
            
        disc.zero_grad()
        d_scaler.scale(D_loss).backward()
        d_scaler.step(opt_disc)
        d_scaler.update()
        
        # train generator
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            
            D_fake = disc(x, y_fake)

            # compute fake loss
            # trick discriminator to believe these are real, hence send in torch.oneslikedfake
            G_fake_loss = bce(D_fake, torch.ones_like(D_fake))

            # compute L1 loss
            L1 = l1(y_fake, y) * args.l1_lambda

            G_loss = G_fake_loss + L1
            
            # log tensorboard
           
        opt_gen.zero_grad()
        g_scaler.scale(G_loss).backward()
        g_scaler.step(opt_gen)
        g_scaler.update()
        
        # print epoch, generator loss, discriminator loss
        print(f'[Epoch {epoch}/{args.num_epochs} (b: {idx})] [D loss: {D_loss}, D real loss: {D_real_loss}, D fake loss: {D_fake_loss}] [G loss: ##{G_loss}, G fake loss: {G_fake_loss}, L1 loss: {L1}]')
        output = f'[Epoch {epoch}/{args.num_epochs} (b: {idx})] [D loss: {D_loss}, D real loss: {D_real_loss}, D fake loss: {D_fake_loss}] [G loss: ##{G_loss}, G fake loss: {G_fake_loss}, L1 loss: {L1}]\n'
        total_output+=output



    runtime_log = get_json_file_from_s3(runtime_log_folder, runtime_log_file_name)
    runtime_log += total_output
    upload_json_file_to_s3(runtime_log_folder,runtime_log_file_name,json.dumps(runtime_log))



def __getitem__(self, index):
    print("Index ",index)
    pair_key = self.list_files[index]
    print("Pair key ",pair_key)
    pair = Boto.s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=Boto.bucket_name, Prefix=pair_key, Delimiter='/')

    input_image_key = pair.get('Contents')[1].get('Key')
    input_image_path = f's3://{Boto.bucket_name}/{input_image_key}'
    print("Input image path ",input_image_path)
    input_image_s3_source = get_file_from_filepath(input_image_path)
    input_image = np.array(Image.open(input_image_s3_source))

    target_image_key = pair.get('Contents')[0].get('Key')
    target_image_path = f's3://{Boto.bucket_name}/{target_image_key}'
    print("Target image path ",target_image_path)
    target_image_s3_source = get_file_from_filepath(target_image_path)
    target_image = np.array(Image.open(target_image_s3_source))

    augmentations = config.both_transform(image=input_image, image0=target_image)

    # get input image and target image by doing augmentations of images
    input_image, target_image = augmentations['image'], augmentations['image0']

    input_image = config.transform_only_input(image=input_image)['image']
    target_image = config.transform_only_mask(image=target_image)['image']
    
    print("Input image size ",input_image.size())
    print("Target image size ",target_image.size())
    
    return input_image, target_image
```

I did multiple runs and here are the traces of the failure points

```
i) 2022-06-03-05-00-04-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training
No index shown
[Epoch 0/100 (b: 0)]

ii) 2022-06-03-05-16-49-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training
Index  160
[Epoch 0/100 (b: 0)]

iii) 2022-06-03-05-44-46-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training
Index  160
[Epoch 0/100 (b: 0)]

iv) 2022-06-03-06-08-33-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training
Index  160
[Epoch 1/100 (b: 0)]

v) 2022-06-15-02-49-20-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training
Index  160
Pair key  datasets/training-data/testing/2022-05-09-14-39-18/match-raws-finals/U12239/P423712/Pair_71/
[Epoch 0/100 (b: 0)

vi) 2022-06-15-02-59-43-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training
Index  64
Pair key  datasets/training-data/testing/2022-05-09-14-39-18/match-raws-finals/U12239/P425642/Pair_27/
[Epoch 0/100 (b: 247)]

vii) 2022-06-15-04-49-33-pix2pix-U12239-2022-05-09-14-39-18-training
Index  64
Pair key  datasets/training-data/testing/2022-05-09-14-39-18/match-raws-finals/U12239/P415414/Pair_124/
No specific epoch
```

My batch size is 248, so as you can see it seems to fail either at the start of the batch (0) or at the end (247). Also there are some common Indexes in the get item which seems to cause it to fail, namely Index 64 and Index 160. However there doesn't seem to be a common data point in the dataset that causes it to fail, as can be seen from the pair key all 3 data points in the datasets are different.

Does anyone have any idea why this error happens please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the same training script outside of a SageMaker training job and see what happens.
If the error doesn't happen on a standalone script, try to run it as a [Local SageMaker training job](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-amazon-sagemaker-local-mode-to-train-on-your-notebook-instance/), so you can reproduce it in seconds instead of minutes, and potentially use a debugger to figure out what is the problem.